# ArcGIS Pro Charts Auto Rounding Inconsistently

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts

I'm making a set of maps and charts in ArcGIS Pro.  I have a scatterplot with a r2 value of 0.06 and another with a value of 0.08.  When I make chart panes, it displays the r2=0.06 as is on the chart, but it auto rounds the r2=0.08 to 0.1 on the chart within the layout.

Is there any work around to fix this glitch/inconsistent behaviour?

I'm doing this as part of a Lab assignment for my students.  I recognize the r2 values aren't really significant, I just want to show them how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I work on the development team at Esri and wanted to reach out.  By default, chart frames in layouts will only show data that is visible in the associated map frame.  In cases where the chart frame is not showing the entire dataset (because some data is not visible in the map frame), the r2 will be calculated using only the subset of data that is displayed on the chart.  In the screenshot you posted, it appears that there are some points missing from the "Monthly Rent vs. Proportion Greenspace" chart frame shown above compared to the “Monthly Rent vs. Proportion Greenspace” chart view shown below, which would explain the different r2 values.

Please see the following documentation page for more details:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/layouts/charts.htm

If you still have questions, feel free to follow up!

**Update**

If you wish to show all data in a chart frame, regardless of whether it is displayed in the map frame, use the following steps:

1. Right-click the chart frame and click **Properties** to display the **Format Chart Frame** pane.
2. On the **Options** tab of the **Format Chart Frame** pane, uncheck the **Only show chart data that is visible in the map frame** checkbox to disable.

This information is in the documentation page linked above, but I’m also including it here.